# How to build a spark data frame based on a nested Json?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to create a new spark data frame using scalabased on a nested JSON.I have defined the case class to map the incoming json.

Sample JSON:

```
{
   "mapper":{
      "fact":[
         {
            "vendorLst":["110","120"],
            "flag":true,
            "upcLst":["10","20","30"],
            "startDate":20190101,
            "endDate":20190130,
            "idVal":"500"
         },
         {
            "vendorLst":["150"],
            "startDate":20180101,
            "endDate":null,
            "subVendorIdValue":null
         }
      ],
      "fact":[
         {
            "vendorLst":["200"],
            "startDate":null,
            "endDate":null,
            "idVal":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Wanted to build the data frame like below. When the flag is true then need to map each vendor with the upc and when the flag is false or not available then mapping between the vendor and upc not needed and the respective data frame column can be updated as null.

```
vendorLst flag  upcLst  startDate   endDate idVal
110   TRUE  10  20190101    20190130    500
110   TRUE  20  20190101    20190130    500
110   TRUE  30  20190101    20190130    500
120   TRUE  10  20190101    20190130    500
120   TRUE  20  20190101    20190130    500
120   TRUE  30  20190101    20190130    500
150   FALSE null    20190101    null    null
200   FALSE null    null    null    null
```

Comment: i'm afraid that you might have to do some *flattening* (processing) yourself before `Spark` can consume to to create a `DataFrame`

Comment: Or you may read the `DataFrame` as it is an do the **flattening** _(processing)_ using Spark. What exactly is your question / problem ?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez here i am trying to build the DF based on the josn. was not very sure, should be doing the flattening in Spark itself or just do that in scala and the build the df in spark.

Comment: @Pradeep Well if you are planning to use **Spark** is because your data should be very big. Assuming that, is always better to do everything inside **Spark** to take advantage of the distributed capabilities of **Spark**. Also, IMHO, it would be easier to do the flattening in **Spark**.

Comment: spark will have a problem parsing this json (i.e. it would parse it but you'd have a problem handling it later) as it doesn't know how to treat the two "fact" sub-jsons - they don't have an array relation between them and they seem to spark like separate fields